# SpringBoot Repository Join Bidirectional

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have the following two entities:

Driver.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "driver")
@Getter @Setter
public class Driver {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int dbid;

    private String lastName;

    private String firstName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "driver")
    private List<Lap> laps;
}
```

Lap.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lap")
@Getter @Setter
public class Lap {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer dbid;

    private Integer entryDbid;

    private Integer lapNumber;

    private Double lapTime;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "driver_dbid")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("laps")
    private Driver driver;
}
```

And now I want to create two Repositories. One for selecting all drivers with there corresponding laps, and another repository for selecting all laps with it's corresponding driver.

LapRepository.java

```
public interface LapRepository extends JpaRepository<Lap, Integer> {

    @Query( value = "SELECT l, d FROM Lap l INNER JOIN l.driver d")
    List<Lap> findWithDriver();
}
```

DriverRepository.java

```
public interface DriverRepository extends JpaRepository<Driver, Integer> {

    @Query( value = "SELECT d FROM Driver d")
    List<Driver> findWithoutLaps();

    @Query( value = "SELECT d, l FROM Driver d INNER JOIN d.laps l")
    List<Driver> findWithLaps();
}
```

the following function call works as expected. Only one query will be executed, and the results will be transformed to the Lap-Entity.

```
List<Lap> laps = this.lapRepository.findWithDriver()
```

Here the log:

```
1796761 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
2003707 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
58061128 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
```

If i want to execute the following:

```
List<Driver> drivers = this.driverRepo.findWithoutLaps()
```

it works as expected, too. Here the n+1 Problem occurs, because the corresponding laps will not be selected in the query.

But here:
    List drivers = this.driverRepo.findWithLaps()

I expect, that the corresponding laps will be selected during the query and will be set on the driver object.
But, I get the following log:

```
761869 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
2337819 nanoseconds spent preparing 87 JDBC statements;
305405297 nanoseconds spent executing 87 JDBC statements;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
```

Furthermore for every single result row, the laps were joined. 
Which means the following for example:
I have 50 Drivers, each of them has 2 Laps -> i get 100 Driver Objects in the Result.

Something is wrong with the query, but I don't know what?

Edit: Here are the postgres tables:

Driver

```
dbid        serial    not null    primary key
first_name  text      not null
last_name   text      not null
```

Lap

```
dbid        serial    not null    primary key
entry_dbid  int       not null    foreign key
driver_dbid int       not null    foreign key
lap_number  int       not null
lap_time    double    not null
```

Answer (score 0):

When you perform an internal union, both tables are taken, as if joining in the same table, you duplicate the register. If you uses DISTINCT don't should have that problem

For example:

```
@Query( value = "SELECT DISTINCT d, l FROM Driver d INNER JOIN d.laps l")
```

Comment: thank you for the replay, but unfortunately the Distinct changes nothing

Comment: Try to use Left Join with Distinct, i´m sure the problem is how join those tables, can you post the sql of those tables? @user2622344